# How to replace a string a particular position with a matched Regular expression pattern at that position

Tags: c#, regex

So, I have this basic program which matches a particular pattern in a string and then stores all the matches in an array. Then I append each matched element to a string.

Now my question is, how can I replace the matched pattern in the original string with the modified string that I generated based on my `regex`.

A sample working program can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UvgOVc

As you can see that the final string generated has the last modified string only. How can I replace the corresponding matches in the replacement?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string url = "Please ab123456 this is and also bc789456 and also de456789 ";
        string[] queryString = getMatch(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}");
        string[] formatted=new string[10000];
        string finalurl=string.Empty;

        for(int i=0;i<queryString.Length;i++)
        {
            formatted[i]="replace "+queryString[i];
            Console.WriteLine(formatted[i]+"\n");
            finalurl=Regex.Replace(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}",formatted[i]);
        }

         Console.WriteLine(finalurl);
    }

    private static string[] getMatch(string text, string expr) 
     {
         string matched=string.Empty;
         string[] matches=new string[100];
         var mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);         
         if ( text != string.Empty && mc.Count > 0)
         {
               matches =  mc.OfType<Match>()
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .ToArray();
         }      
        return matches;
      }
}
```

Output:

```
replace ab123456

replace bc789456

replace de456789

Please replace de456789 this is and also replace de456789 and also replace de456789
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more info on what should be the desired output string? Because right now the program you wrote does exactly what has been written, it replaces every occurence that matches a Regex with the string "formatted ....".
So what should actually be the desired output, where should we end up starting from the input string?

Comment: Currently, you might as well just use `string finalurl=Regex.Replace(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}", "replace $&");`. No need for any for loop. No need of `getMatch` either, just use `string[] queryString = Regex.Matches(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();`, see https://ideone.com/2Yxzy5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your first comment is great and works as expected but it does not use the second comment which is the `queryString` variable. Is there a way to keep a track of the indices in the matches and replace them accordingly? This is just out of curiosity

Comment: @RahulSharma What do you need to do?

Comment: Point is you don't need that variable once you use the correct `Regex.Replace` syntax

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution has already answered my question sir. I just wanted to understand that if there is way in which (if I had used) the `string[] queryString` method, how would I have kept a track of the corresponding matches in the `Replace` method in the original `url` string and replaced them accordingly (may be using indices).

Comment: I am pretty sure you just want to use a match evaluator, see the bottom of my answer. No need to track the indices, although you may of course, but that is too tricky since you will need to keep track of constantly changing offsets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, makes sense.Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to

```
string url = "Please ab123456 this is and also bc789456 and also de456789 ";
string[] queryString = Regex.Matches(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
string finalurl=Regex.Replace(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}", "replace $&");
Console.WriteLine(finalurl); // => Please replace ab123456 this is and also replace bc789456 and also replace de456789
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/2Yxzy5).

Here, `Regex.Matches(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()` collects all matches into the `queryString` variable (if you need the match values array).

The `Regex.Replace(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}", "replace $&")` finds all matches of two word chars followed with six digits and appends `replace` + space before the matched texts (note `$&` is the backreference to the whole match value).

If you plan to perform some more manipulation with the found matches, consider using a match evaluator. Say, you defined `SomeMethod(string s)` somewhere, then you may  use

```
string finalurl=Regex.Replace(url,@"\w{2}\d{6}", m =>
    SomeMethod(m.Value);
);
```

Comment: `queryString` is unnecessary here since you don't use that variable in the code. Might reduce execution time and memory costs a bit

Comment: @FrancescoGimignano That is why  I added *(if you need the match values array)* If a user needs both the matches and the new string, it is OK to keep it in the answer.